# Value cannot be null or empty. Parameter name: contentPath

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am facing a strange issue with my MVC application, everything works fine i don't know what happened to this app now. I just update all the nuget packages.
Getting the below error

`Value cannot be null or empty. Parameter name: contentPath at`

Error Location

`@System.Web.Optimization.Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")
@System.Web.Optimization.Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")`

i did not change anything to bundles configuration and i have all the required scripts.
here is that complete stack trace

> Exception: System.ArgumentException: Value cannot be null or empty.
>   Parameter name: contentPath at
>   System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper.GenerateContentUrl(String contentPath,
>   HttpContextBase httpContext) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper.Content(String contentPath) at
>   System.Dynamic.UpdateDelegates.UpdateAndExecute2[T0,T1,TRet](CallSite
>   site, T0 arg0, T1 arg1) at
>   ASP._Page_Views_Shared__AdminLayout_cshtml.Execute() in f:\Sample
>   Projects\Notebook\Notebook\Views\Shared_AdminLayout.cshtml:line 23 at
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy() at
>   System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage.ExecutePageHierarchy() at
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext
>   pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) at
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext
>   pageContext, TextWriter writer) at
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.<>c_*DisplayClass7.b*_6(TextWriter
>   writer) at System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult.WriteTo(TextWriter writer)
>   at System.Web.WebPages.WebPageExecutingBase.WriteTo(TextWriter writer,
>   HelperResult content) at
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.Write(HelperResult result) at
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.RenderSurrounding(String
>   partialViewName, Action`1 body) at
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.PopContext() at
>   System.Web.WebPages.WebPageBase.ExecutePageHierarchy(WebPageContext
>   pageContext, TextWriter writer, WebPageRenderingBase startPage) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.RazorView.RenderView(ViewContext viewContext,
>   TextWriter writer, Object instance) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.BuildManagerCompiledView.Render(ViewContext
>   viewContext, TextWriter writer) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ViewResultBase.ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResult(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1
>   filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext,
>   ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1
>   filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext,
>   ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1
>   filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext,
>   ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultFilterRecursive(IList`1
>   filters, Int32 filterIndex, ResultExecutingContext preContext,
>   ControllerContext controllerContext, ActionResult actionResult) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionResultWithFilters(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IList`1 filters, ActionResult actionResult) at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c_*DisplayClass21.<>c*_DisplayClass2b.b_*1c()
>   at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c*_DisplayClass21.b__1e(IAsyncResult
>   asyncResult)

Comment: Do you have something like `"@Url.Content("")"` there (Razor)?

Comment: yes. `@Url.Content(ViewBag.UserImageUrl)`

Comment: `ViewBag.UserImageUrl` is null or empty ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are calling `@Url.Content(ViewBag.UserImageUrl)` with a null / empty argument.

Place a breakpoint before the call and inspect `ViewBag.UserImageUrl`.